# Adding 3 blocks of AdSense shows errors

Tags: adsense

I need to add 3 ads in a page. I have created those ads in AdSense console, then, I added this code once in the page, before `</head>`:

```
​​<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-7744644029571866"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

At the end of the page, I added:

```
<script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Finally, inside the DIV's where I need the ads to appear, I added:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-client"
     data-ad-slot="myslot"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
```

After that, when I load the page, these errors are shown in browser console:

- adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=80
- adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=80
- adsbygoogle.push() error: All ins elements in the … with
  class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In very top of Head of HTML Add

```
<style>
.adsbygoogle {position:relative;width:100%;}
</style>
```

or Manually Define Adsize by acceptable Admodification

```
<style>
.example_responsive_1 { width: 300px; height: 250px; }
@media(min-width: 500px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media(min-width: 800px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
</style>
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXX" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- example_responsive_1 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle example_responsive_1"
     style="display:inline-block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXX"
     data-ad-slot="YYYY"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: The same happen, but now for Width = 0. adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0, and no ad is shown.

Comment: Hi, I have added one more answer that would be the suitable solution for you.